# I'm a beginner and I can't solve some errors within C# code

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm new to C# and I'm currently learning  it step by step and I also exercise at every chapter. I'm trying to make a small mad lipz game with what I learned so far but it's not working, something is missing and I think it has to be with the functions.

I'm getting these errors :

> CS0103 The name 'color' does not exist in the current context

> CS0103 The name 'noun' does not exist in the current context

> CS0103 The name 'person' does not exist in the current context

My code:

```
using System;

namespace Tutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Words();
           Game(); 
            
           Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Words()
        {
             Console.Write(" Write a color: ");
             string color = Console.ReadLine();

             Console.Write(" Write a noun: ");
             string noun = Console.ReadLine();

             Console.Write(" Write a person: ");
             string person = Console.ReadLine();
         }

         static void Game()
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Roses are " + color);
              Console.WriteLine( noun + " is dead ");
              Console.WriteLine("I should vote " + person); 
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Where** you declare a variable determines its *scope*.  Those variables are declared in `Words` so they do not exist in `Game`.

Answer (score 1):

`color`, `noun` and `person` are local variables in the `Words` method, and cannot be used outside of it. One way to solve this problem is to declare them as (static) members instead of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of the program. The function `Words()` does not know of the variables, as they are defined in the function `Game()`. One possible solution would be to add the three variables as parameters to the function `Words()`.

```
static void Game(string person, string color, string noun) {}
```